# Ruby on Rails - ArgumentError (Call this with at least one field):

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying to replica the following query in `ActiveRecords` model, currently in `Ticket`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tickets
WHERE tickets.status = 'open' AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages INNER JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.id WHERE messages.commentable_id = tickets.id AND users.admin = true) = 0
```

I have a scope that filters by `opened` status:

```
scope :opened, -> { where(status: 'open') }
```

And now I created another scope, `unanswered` to use it:

```
  scope :unanswered, -> {
    opened.all.where(select.joins('INNER JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.id').where('messages.commentable_id = tickets.id AND users.admin = true').count.zero?)
  }
```

And then it gives me this error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 5.5ms)

ArgumentError (Call this with at least one field):
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you phrase the query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t.id)
FROM tickets t LEFT JOIN
     messages m
     ON m.commentable_id = t.id LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON m.user_id = u.id AND u.admin = true
WHERE t.status = 'open' AND u.id IS NULL;
```

Then perhaps it will be easier to transform.

Comment: So I could do it like `opened.joins('LEFT JOIN messages ON messages.commentable_id = tickets.id LEFT JOIN users ON messages.user_id = users.id AND users.admin = true').where("users.id IS NULL").distinct` ?

Comment: I don't know.  I write raw SQL.

Comment: DISTINCT basically clears up duplicates so it only show one id?

Comment: @Jony . . . Yes, that is what `select distinct` does.